# How do I do this in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
SELECT client_name,mid_number,user_name,PASSWORD 
FROM automation_run_log 
WHERE LENGTH(schedule_status="FAILED") > 0 
GROUP BY client_name
```

My code:

```
automationRunLog.findAll({
    attributes : ["clientName","midNumber","userName","password"],
    where      : sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('length',      sequelize.col('schedule_status')),"FAILED"),
    group      : ['clientName']
    }).then(function (clientDtls) {
    console.log(clientDtls)
})
```

Where do I give `$gt:0` in where clause?

Answer (score 0):

I havent got time to try it but this should work:

```
automationRunLog.findAll({
  attributes : ["clientName","midNumber","userName","password"],
  where      : sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('length', 
               sequelize.col('schedule_status')),"FAILED", {$gt: 0}),
  group      : ['clientName']
}).then(function (clientDtls) {
  console.log(clientDtls)
})
```